# System.Drawing.Imaging: What type does PropertyItem.Type = 9 correspond to?

Tags: c#, image, system.drawing.imaging

I'm using System.Drawing.Image to load a JPG image.

I found an image that has an EXIF orientation tag (0x0112) of type=9, len=4

Usually when I load an image, I get Type = 3 (Array of uint16, len = 2(bytes)).  One clue is when I run it through EXIFTool( http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ ), I noticed that the Exif Byte Order is Little-endian (Intel, II).  So, I'm kind of thinking that either the EXIF processing in System.Drawing.Image doesn't support this byte order or that I need to somehow transpose the bytes from Little Endian -> Big Endian?  The number of bytes isn't right though for that.  Some of my other images that parse correctly are Big Endian (haven't checked them all yet though).

In the docs for PropertyItem.Type, 9 isn't listed:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type(v=vs.110).aspx

relevant code snippet:

```
    public static Image RemoveImageOrientation(this Image imageIn)
    {
        if(imageIn.HasOrientationExifTag())
        {
            var orientationPropItem = imageIn.GetPropertyItem((int)ImagePropertyItemMetaData.PropertyTagOrientation);

            if(orientationPropItem.Type != 3 // array of uint16
                || orientationPropItem.Len != 2) // only one 1 uint (2 bytes)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to parse orientation EXIF tag.  Type = " + orientationPropItem.Type + ", len = " + orientationPropItem.Len);
            }

            var orientationExifTag = BitConverter.ToUInt16(orientationPropItem.Value, 0);
```

Comment: It is [PropertyTagTypeSLONG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534414(v=vs.85).aspx).